# WPF Binding to Collection and updating when collection changes

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using a ItemsControl and binding it's ItemsSource to a collection (empty) property in my ModelView.

It's a form for new users, so when the client clicks a button, I want to add a new Model to the collection and want the ItemsControl to display the template.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding UserView.Users}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0, 0, 0, 5">
                <!-- My layout here -->
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

If I add new users to the list on my `Users` ModelView constructor, the ItemsControl are filled properly, but nothing happens if I add (or remove) an item from the collection from the button's click event.

How can I make it so the bind updates whenever the contents of the collection change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `UserView.Users` property an `ObservableCollection` and it will notify the binding system for you whenever there is a change.